# MySQL database in GitHub folder

Tags: java, mysql, git, github, mysql-workbench

I'm new to GitHub and have a Java application in my local GitHub folder. It works like a charm to commit and push etc. Now I would like to add a MySQL database to this folder as well.

Is this wise, or should I keep it in the default Workbench folder that I normally use. I just figured it would make sense to have all the version controlled projects and data in the GitHub folder, especially as the java application depends on the MySQL datasource and will need to be updated frequently as the schema is developed incrementally along with the app.

Workbench doesn't give me any location options when creating a new schema.

Is my approach to keep everything that will be on GitHub in the GitHub folder reasonable? How do I accomplish this when it comes to relational data and do you have any other suggestions where to keep the local data for my GitHub project?

Comment: try this http://flywaydb.org/

Answer (score 4):

Storing an actual database in git will not work at all.

However, you should store the SQL / DDL code used to generate the database in git.
You should be able to recreate the base state of the database from your git repo.